# From a given node get reachable node following unidirectional relationship and display that sub-graph as a tree

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

here is my problem:

I've got a graph where I have `:Item` with one relationship `:CRAFTED_WITH` to one `:RECIPE` and those `:RECIPE`have one or more relationship `:COMPOSED_OF{quantity}` to ingredients that are `:Item`.

As you can imagine you can have several level of relationship to get from a high tier `:Item` to the most basic of components.

I want to be able to find all nodes that are reachable from a specific node while following only one direction. That part was easy I used the `apoc` procedure `apoc.path.subgraphAll`.

But now my next step is to have the result display as a tree and not a graph. In a graph I will ended up with multiple `:Item` on the receiving end of `:COMPOSED_OF` relationship. I want `:Item` to be "duplicated" so they are linked by a single `:COMPOSED_OF` relationship.

Is it even feasible only in `cypher` ? Or will I have to use another language to handle a graph to turn it into that "tree" structure ?

Answer (score 0):

There is an apoc function to do that. The cypher below illustrates what is does.

```
MATCH treePath=(root:Thing)-[:CHILD*0..]->(leaf:Thing)
WHERE NOT (leaf)-[:CHILD]->()
      AND NOT ()-[:CHILD]->(root)
WITH COLLECT(treePath) AS treePaths
CALL apoc.convert.toTree(treePaths) yield value AS tree
RETURN tree
```

Comment: I'll give it a try after my job and give you some feedback ;-)